# Active Directory historical membership

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

Is it possible to tell if a user *was* a member of a group on a given date in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to tell if a user was a member of a given group on a given date based solely on the data stored in Active Directory because Active Directory only stores current content, not historical content.

I suppose if you had some sort of a 3rd party solution in place that were taking snapshots of Active Directory on a regular basis and then archiving them, you might have a shot at obtaining this answer.

Comment: +1. THAT SAID: if you need auditing, implement auditing as said: regular snapshots to a database.